# Finding the latest file for a particular date and then opening files over a specified date range

Tags: excel, vba, loops, date, range

So, I haven't written any particular code for this yet, but am trying to think conceptually about how to do it.

I have a folder where a .xslx file is dumped every hour of every working day. At the moment I have some code which goes in, finds the most recent file and opens it, does some data manipulation (filter, copy then paste to another workbook, etc).

What i want now is to create a time-series, so for e.g. i specify a range of dates say 1st March 2021 to 1st June 2021, have the code find the latest file for each working day in that range, open it and perform the same data manipulation steps i have already created.

If helpful below is my current code which just finds the most recent file (of any date). My question is how do i go about looping through the files? Do i need a new variable, or can i change dtefile as a range of dates?

```
Sub LatestLoad()

Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
Dim objFile As File
Dim myFolder
Dim strFilename As String
Dim dteFile As Date

    Const myDir As String = "C:\myfolder"

    Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject
    Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)
   
    dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
    For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
        If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
            dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
            strFilename = objFile.Name
        End If
    Next objFile
    Workbooks.Open myDir & "\" & strFilename, ReadOnly:=True
    Workbooks(strFilename).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: `If objFile.DateLastModified >= DateSerial(2021, 3, 1) And objFile.DateLastModified < DateSerial(2021, 6, 1) Then` should  loop through all files between those dates. Whas that your question?

Comment: half of it, i think - i also want to open each of the last modified file on each date?

Comment: You mean you need to find the last modified file of each day between those 2 dates?

Comment: Just an input to a conceptual question: This might rather be a job for a database. You fill the data into a database and you can query whatever selection of data you need. Where do the Excel files come from? From a database? There might be a straight way to the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to collect the desired files and then loop the dictionary to do your things.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LatestLoad()
    Dim strFilename As String
    
    Const myDir As String = "C:\temp"

    Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
    Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject

    Dim myFolder As Variant
    Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)
   
    Dim dteStart As Date
    dteStart = DateSerial(2021, 3, 1)

    Dim dteEnd As Date
    dteEnd = DateSerial(2021, 6, 1)
    
    ' we want to collect all last modified files per day in a dictionary
    Dim LastModFileList As Object
    Set LastModFileList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim objFile As File
    For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
        If objFile.DateLastModified >= dteStart And objFile.DateLastModified < dteEnd Then ' check if file is within desired range
            If LastModFileList.Exists(CLng(objFile.DateLastModified)) Then ' check if day already exists in dictionary
                If LastModFileList(CLng(objFile.DateLastModified)).DateLastModified < objFile.DateLastModified Then ' check if current file is older then the one already in the dictionary
                    Set LastModFileList(CLng(objFile.DateLastModified)) = objFile ' set the older file to the dictionary
                End If
            Else ' for this day no file was tracked yet so add the current one
                LastModFileList.Add CLng(objFile.DateLastModified), objFile
            End If
        End If
    Next objFile
    
    ' now all last modified files per day are in the dictionary
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In LastModFileList.Keys ' loop through the dictionary and do things
        Debug.Print Format$(Key, "yyyy-mm-dd"), myDir & "\" & LastModFileList(Key).Name
        'do your work for each file here (open/edit/close)
    Next Key
End Sub
```